# What are the updates for Twitter Bootstrap v3.1.1 and are they much different then v3.0.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am curious to know if full integration of Sass is available in v3.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much serious changes on new 3.1.1 version

All the changes are mentioned here

http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/02/13/bootstrap-3-1-1-released/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was hoping to get feedback from developers actually using the latest version. Also, any idea if v3.1.1 fully supports Sass.

Comment: @JBlazeCoder21 Yes, it does. I am working on official bootstrap now. It is really easy and fun. especially on variable.scss file :)

Comment: Good, stuff. Any opinion on downloading through Initialzr vs straight from the source. I have posted this as a separate post.

Comment: @JBlazeCoder21 Sorry I don't understand understand the question. Could you explain the question please

Comment: I has also posted other questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462334/what-features-do-you-gain-lose-with-h5bp-and-bootstrap-when-using-intilializr

Comment: @JBlazeCoder21 they have implemented the latest version of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

maybe the best place to check this is in the bootstrap blog:

I really dont think there are important changes.

http://blog.getbootstrap.com/