# What features do you gain/lose with H5BP and Bootstrap when using intilializr?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate, initializr

Curious to hear peoples experience with initializr, rather than downloading H5BP or Bootstrap right from the source. The differences, gains/losses of tools, and challenges.

Answer (score 0):

**initializr** implemented the latest version of bootstrap :)

[image]